# Angular reactive forms: Is there any sense in the FormControl -> get() method?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In Angular Reactive Forms, `FormControl` inherits [get()](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.7/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L670) method from `AbstractControl`. This method then call [_find()](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.7/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L47-L66) method, where parameter `control` it's `FormControl`:

```ts
function _find(control: AbstractControl, path: Array<string|number>| string, delimiter: string) {
  if (path == null) return null;

  if (!(path instanceof Array)) {
    path = (<string>path).split(delimiter);
  }
  if (path instanceof Array && (path.length === 0)) return null;

  return (<Array<string|number>>path).reduce((v: AbstractControl, name) => {
    if (v instanceof FormGroup) {
      return v.controls.hasOwnProperty(name as string) ? v.controls[name] : null;
    }

    if (v instanceof FormArray) {
      return v.at(<number>name) || null;
    }

    return null;
  }, control);
}
```

As we can see, this method searching `path` (!)only in `FormGroup` and `FormArray`.

So, is there any sense in the FormControl -> get() method? Can I just not know about a case where this method is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Probably its not necessary. I don't find any logic for control to have get. Since Group, Array and control all get methods from AbstractControl, that's why the get method appeared at control.

Answer (score 0):

You has two methods to get a control in a formGroup

```
myForm.controls.name_of_control
//and
myForm.get('name_of_control')
```

Using "get" sure that if Angular change the "model" of a formGroup(*), this change not affected to your code

(*)Imagine that in a newer version of Angular, the controls are stored in a property called "customControls" not in  "controls" never more, The Angular team will change the function "get()" to give your control, but you loose the myForm.controls becaosue this property has dissapear

Comment: How about formControl.get()?

Comment: ::glups:: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Sincerally, For me, has no sense, a FormControl has no children, so, in a formControl must be return null always. As FormControl, FormArray and FormGroup extends AbstractControl, must be a method "get" in all of them, FormControl  must have the method but, as I say, this method should return null (or undefined)